# ブロック崩しゲームの制作を試みたのですが、オーバーフローのエラーが出ました。なぜですか？

Tags: vba, excel

書いたコードとシートの画像です

```
Dim vx, vy, dt, x, y As Single
Dim k, n, v As Integer
Dim b_px(100), b_py(100), b_vx(100), b_vy(100) As Single
Dim losted() As Single

Sub ball()
    dt = Cells(2, 5)
    vx = Cells(5, 2)
    vy = Cells(5, 3)
    x = Cells(2, 2).Value
    y = Cells(2, 3).Value
    v = 0

Do
    Calculate
        x = x + vx * dt
        y = y + vy * dt
    For k = 1 To 2
        Cells(3, 2) = x
        Cells(3, 3) = y
        DoEvents
    Next k
    DoEvents
    Call wallball
        If Cells(3, 3) <= 0.28 Then
            MsgBox "GameOver"
            Exit Do
        Else
    End If
    Call breakball
Loop

For I = 0 To v - 1

    If losted(I) >= 8 Then
        Cells(10 + losted(I), 2) = losted(I) + 1
        Cells(10 + losted(I), 3) = 9
    Else
        Cells(10 + losted(I), 2) = losted(I) - 8
        Cells(10 + losted(I), 3) = 8
    End If
Next I
End Sub

Sub wallball()
    Select Case Cells(3, 2).Value
        Case Is >= 9.72
            vx = -1 * vx
        Case Is <= 0.28
            vx = -1 * vx
    End Select
    Select Case Cells(3, 3).Value
        Case Is >= 9.72
            vy = -1 * vy
    End Select
End Sub

Sub breakball()
    For n = 0 To 17
            b_px(n) = Cells(10 + n, 2)
            b_py(n) = Cells(10 + n, 3)
        If y > b_py(n) - 0.55 And y < b_py(n) + 0.55 Then
                If x < b_px(n) + 0.6 And x > b_px(n) - 0.6 Then
                        vx = -1 * vx
                        Cells(10 + n, 2) = 0
                        Cells(10 + n, 3) = -1
                        ReDim losted(v)
                        losted(v) = n
                        v = v + 1
                        Cells(8, 2) = v
                        DoEvents
                    Else
                End If
            Else
        End If
    
        If x > b_px(n) - 0.55 And x < b_px(n) + 0.55 Then
                If y < b_py(n) + 0.6 And y > b_py(n) - 0.6 Then
                        vy = -1 * vy
                        Cells(10 + n, 2) = 0
                        Cells(10 + n, 3) = -1
                         ReDim losted(v)
                        losted(v) = n
                        v = v + 1
                        Cells(8, 2) = v
                        DoEvents
                    Else
                End If
            Else
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: 他の人が問題を再現・調査できるように発生している現象や問題の詳細を詳細に記述してください。例えばエラーメッセージは表示されたままをすべて略さずにテキストで書いてみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) それからデバッグ実行で細かく状況を調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [【超初心者向け】エクセルVBAでデバッグをする方法を解説します](https://www.excelspeedup.com/vbadebug/), [【ExcelVBA入門】VBAでデバッグするための方法とは？](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/66208)

Answer (score 0):

画像を見て判断できるのでは、キャラクター画像を描いたシートがなく、VBAのコードが参照されていなかったり、パラメーターのシートも値が参照されてないのでそのままでは出来ないと思います。Excelでゲームするのは、メモリを使うのであまりお薦めしません。